# wpa_supplicant + dhclient loose connection when downloading file of 4Gb

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant, guix

I have two wifi-adapters: inner and usb. I always use external usb wifi adapter, because it shows better signal power and better speed. It started to loose connection every day twice or 4-5 times a day and need to reconnect. I can't find the reason.

Now, when I try to download a file size 4Gb it looses connection after 600 Mb or 1.2Gb downloaded. I tried another wifi adapter (inner) - it does the same!

I use wpa_supplicant + dhclient. Wpa-supplicant works as Herd service.

I do not know how does my computer get IP may be with the service 'networking' in Herd.

Now when I connected with ethernet cable internet is stable. I stopped wpa-supplicant service in herd, and here are log messages in /var/log/messages:

```
# tail /var/log/messages
Jan  4 16:57:26 localhost dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jan  4 17:03:45 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jan  4 17:03:50 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jan  4 17:03:58 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jan  4 17:04:08 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jan  4 17:04:22 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jan  4 17:04:37 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jan  4 17:04:46 localhost dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jan  4 17:04:46 localhost dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.


# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 


network={
    ssid="ssidemyhidethessid"
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=WPA2
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk=passthepassypass
}

# uname -a
Linux antelope 5.10.4-gnu #1 SMP 1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# readlink /sys/class/net/wlp0s20f0u2/device/driver
../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc
```

OS Guix.

Could you please help to find what can I do for better wifi connection?